# How to count the number of times a substring (word) has appeared in a string using tuples

Tags: swift

You are given an array of strings stored in the variable strings. Create a new array named countedStrings containing values of type (String, Int). Each tuple contains a string from the strings array followed by an integer indicating how many times it appears in the strings array. Each string should only appear once in the countedStrings array.

I have not solved the problem as It is already solved. I am just trying to understand it. Some part of it I could understand and some parts I could not. I could not understand the portion inside the for loops.

```
 var a =  ["tuples", "are", "awesome", "tuples", "are", "cool","tuples",  "tuples", "tuples", "shades"]

 var y: [(String,Int)] = []

  for z in a{ 
  var x = false

  for i in 0..<y.count {
  if (y[i].0 == z) {
  y[i].1 += 1
  x = true
   }
   }
   if x == false {
   y.append((z,1))
    }
    }
    print(y)
```

Prints

> [("tuples", 5), ("are", 2), ("awesome", 1), ("cool", 1), ("shades", 1)] cool", 1), ("shades", 1)]

Comment: @Yoam Already provided a nice explanation for this piece of code. Having said that, this particular problem can be solved with a [counted set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) in a much more efficient way in a couple of lines with something like `let wordSet = NSCountedSet(array: words); let countedList = wordSet.map { ($0, wordSet.count(for: $0)) }`

Comment: @ Alladinian - Thanks. When I type this into compiler -  
let words = ["tuples", "are", "awesome", "tuples", "are", "cool","tuples",  "tuples", "tuples", "shades"]
let wordSet = NSCountedSet(array: words); let countedList = wordSet.map { ($0, wordSet.count(for: $0)) }    , it shows error - code:2:5: error: 'wordSet' used within its own type let wordSet = NSCountedSet(array: words); let countedList = wordSet.map { ($0, wordSet.count(for: $0)) } ^ code:2:5: error: could not infer type for 'wordSet' let wordSet = NSCountedSet(array: words); ...... etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you encounter a problem like this, try to rename the variables first. It helps tremendously with understanding the problem.

For exemple I took your code and just changed the variable names for clarity. Now tell me if there is still something that you don't get.

```
let words = ["tuples", "are", "awesome", "tuples", "are", "cool","tuples",  "tuples", "tuples", "shades"]

var tuples: [(String, Int)] = []

for word in words {
    var isAlreadyInTupleArray = false

    // Loop trough the existing tuples and updates the number of apparition if the word is found
    for (index, tuple) in tuples.enumerated() {
        let tupleWord:String = tuple.0
        let numberOfAppearances:Int = tuple.1

        if tupleWord == word {
            tuples[index].1 += 1

            isAlreadyInTupleArray = true
        }
    }

    // In the case the word was not in the existing tuples, we append a new tuple
    if isAlreadyInTupleArray == false {
        tuples.append((word, 1))
    }
}
print(tuples)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let arr = ["tuples", "are", "awesome", "tuples", "are", "cool","tuples",  "tuples", "tuples", "shades"]
 var counts:[String:Int] = [:]

 for item in arr {
    counts[item] = (counts[item] ?? 0) + 1
 }
 for (key, value) in counts {
    print("\(key) occurs \(value) time(s)")
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, its working, though does not print in the format asked in the question. It prints - 
awesome 1 time(s) 
tuples 5 time(s) 
are 2 time(s) 
cool 1 time(s) 
shades 1 time(s). It should pint- [("tuples", 5), ("are", 2), ("awesome", 1), ("cool", 1), ("shades", 1)]

Comment: print(counts) it print like 
["tuples": 5, "awesome": 1, "are": 2, "cool": 1, "shades": 1]
You can just play with print() function and print it as per your requirement